# Develop Windows programs with Flutter, How to disable IME？

Tags: windows, flutter, flutter-windows

I am using Flutter to develop a Windows program, Need to disable input method, Find the relevant documentation, you can use the `ImmDisableIME(0)` method to disable the input method. But when I try to call this method, An exception was reported when running the project.

[main.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVvJs.png)

[win32_window.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gd9V.png)

How to properly disable the input method?

Comment: I'll answer the question anyway, but in general, please don't post links or pictures of code. Inline the code directly as text along with the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An exception was reported when running the project

No.  An exception was not reported when *running* the project. Rather, your program never ran to begin with because it had a *compiler error*.

Because you are passing **`-1`** to a function expecting an **unsigned integer** (DWORD), the compiler is warning you ([C4245](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4245?view=msvc-170)). And your build environment treats warnings as errors ([C2220](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2220?view=msvc-170)).

To invoke it with -1 such that it disables for all threads in the current process, then invoke it as follows with a cast. It's as easy as that.

```
DWORD dwParam = (DWORD)(-1);
ImmDisableIME(dwParam);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. A lot of websites mentioned that the parameter should simply be -1 to disable all threads in this process. [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sdk-api/blob/docs/sdk-api-src/content/immdev/nf-immdev-immdisableime.md). I tried using 0 or 1 but it still produces the error.

Comment: `main.obj : error LNK2019: �޷��������ⲿ���� ImmDisableIME������ wWinMain �������˸÷��� [W:\WorkSpace\RouXinPai\workpad\build\windows\runner\workpad.vcxproj]
W:\WorkSpace\RouXinPai\workpad\build\windows\runner\Debug\workpad.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 ���޷��������ⲿ���� [W:\WorkSpace\RouXinPai\workpad\build\windows\runner\workpad.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.`

Comment: You are correct. `-1` means "disable for all threads in the process". Hence use a cast. I've updated my answer above, but effectively you can call it as: `ImmDisableIME((DWORD)-1);`

Comment: After inquiring some information, finally disabled the input method. First, add `#pragma comment(lib, "imm32.lib")` to the header of the `win32_window.cpp` file, Then call the `ImmDisableIME(GetCurrentThreadId())` method. Thank you for your help.&( ^___^ )&